# Solution of recurrence

Tags: recurrence-relations, recursion

I need some explanations at the proof of the following theorem.

**Theorem:**

Let $a$, $b$ and $c$ be nonnegative constants.

The solution to the recurrence $$T(n)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
b & ,\text{ for } n=1\\ 
aT(n/c)+bn & ,\text{ for } n>1
\end{matrix}\right.$$ 
for $n$ a power of $c$ is $$T(n)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
O(n) & ,\text{ if } a<c\\ 
O(n \log n) & ,\text{ if } a=c\\ 
O(n^{\log_c a}) & ,\text{ if } a>c
\end{matrix}\right.$$

**Proof:**

If $n$ is a power of $c$, then $$T(n)=bn \sum_{i=0}^{\log_c n} r^i, \text{ where } r=a/c$$

If $a<c$, then $\displaystyle{\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}r^i}$ converges, so $T(n)$ is $O(n)$.

If $a=c$, then each term in the sum is unity, and there are $O(\log n)$ terms. Thus $T(n)$ is $O(n \log n)$.

Finally, if $a>c$ then $\displaystyle{bn\sum_{i=0}^{\log_c n} r^i=bn\frac{r^{1+\log_c n}-1}{r-1}}$, which is $O(a^{\log_c n})$ or equivalently $O(n^{\log_c a})$.

$$$$

My questions are the following:

1. Why is $T(n)$ equal to $bn \sum_{i=0}^{\log_c n} r^i$, where $r=a/c$ if $n$ is a power of $c$ ??
2. If $a<c$: why does $\displaystyle{\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}r^i}$ converge??
3. If $a=c$: why is each term of the sum unity??
4. If $a>c$: why does $\displaystyle{bn\sum_{i=0}^{\log_c n} r^i=bn\frac{r^{1+\log_c n}-1}{r-1}}$ only in this case??

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $n=c^k$. In this case $k=\log_cn$. 
\begin{align}
T(1) &= 1\\
T(c) &= aT(1)+bc=ab+bc=bc\big(\frac{a}{c}+1\big)=bc(1+r)\\
T(c^2)&= aT(c)+bc^2=aT(c)+bc^2=bc^2(1+r+r^2)\\
\cdots\\
T(c^k)&=aT(c^{k-1})+bc^k=bc^k\sum_{j=0}^{\log_cn} r^j.
\end{align}
Remember $r=\frac{a}{c}$ and geometric seri $\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}r^j$ converges iff $|r|<1$ and in this case the partial sum of the series is $\frac{1-r^n}{1-r}$ and the geometric series diverges iff $|r|>1$. The answer for the questions 2-4.

Comment: If $a<c$ : $|r|=\left |\frac{a}{c} \right |<1$ so the series $\displaystyle{ \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}r^i}$ converges and the partial sum of the series is $\displaystyle{\frac{1-r^k}{1-r}}$. How do we conclude that $T(n)=O(n)$ ??

$$$$

If $a=c$ : What does it mean that each term in the sum is unity ??

$$$$

If $a>c$ : The geometric series diverges, right?? Is the partial sum of the series also in this case $\displaystyle{\frac{1-r^k}{1-r}}$ ??

Comment: $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} r^i=\frac{1-r^n}{1-r}$ for all $n$ not important what $r$ is. If $a=c$ then $r=1$ and so each term in the series is 1. This is obvious.

Comment: So, is it as followed??

$$$$

If $a<c$, then $|r|<1$. So, the geometric series $\displaystyle{\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}r^i}$ converges. The partial sum of the series is $\displaystyle{\frac{1-r^{k+1}}{1-r}}$.
Therefore, $$T(n)=bn \sum_{i=0}^{\log_c n}r^i=bn \frac{1-r^{\log_c n+1}}{1-r} \leq bn\frac{1}{1-r}=\frac{b}{1-r}n=\frac{bc}{c-a}n$$
So, $T(n)=O(n)$.

$$$$

If $a=c$, then $$T(n)=bn \sum_{i=0}^{\log_c n}r^i=bn \sum_{i=0}^{\log_c n} 1=bn(\log_c n+1)$$

So, $T(n)=O(n \log n)$.

Comment: If $a>c$, then $$bn \sum_{i=0}^{\log_c n}r^i=bn \frac{1-r^{\log_c n+1}}{1-r} =bn \frac{1-rr^{\log_c n}}{1-r}=bn \frac{1-a/c(a/c)^{\log_c n}}{1-a/c}=bn \frac{\frac{a \cdot a^{\log_c n}}{nc^{\log_c n}}}{1-a/c} \leq bn \frac{a \cdot a^{\frac{\log_c n}{nc}}}{1-a/c}= \frac{aba^{\log_c n}}{a-c}$$

So, $T(n)=O(a^{\log_c n})=O(n^{\log_c a})$.

Comment: yes, you did well.

Comment: Nice!!! If the number of subproblems were $3$, $4$, or $8$, then how can I find of which order the algorithm is?? $3$, $4$, and $8$ is is the formula $a$, or not?? What is $c$?